# Make an UIImageView Fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to make an image go full screen on tap, which doesn't sound so complicated.

This it currently doing the work after the tap is detected:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if (self.contentView.frame.origin.y >= 0 && CGRectContainsPoint(self.bottleImageView.frame, touchLocation)) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        [bottleImageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        bottleImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
...
}
```

There's a problem though. I need to bring the UIImageView to the front, so that it draws the image in front of the other views. When I add in `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bottleImageView];` to the mix (either before the animation block, in the completion block, or after this code), things change. On the first tap, the UIImageView background changes to black, and on the second tap the view expands to full screen.

I'm sure it's just something small and dumb that I've overlooked.

**EDIT:** I've added the touch code

**EDIT (2):** I may have missed some vital information. I thought I'd try auto layout for this project. I'm guessing there's something there that's not letting everything work as intended?

Comment: Can you post your tap detection code, that calls the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The code above is fine for expanding a view.

I found there was a problem with the Autolayout restraints. I couldn't tell you exactly what I changed that fixed the problem - but a few hours debugging restraints solved the issue.

I found a much better solution however - [Facebook POP](https://github.com/facebook/pop) works much better, and looks a lot slicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MHFacebookImageViewer](https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHFacebookImageViewer)

for this purpose. It is very simple to use.

Comment: Hi, This does look nice, and I might just use that. I'm a bit confused as to why the code above doesn't work though :s

Comment: Works for me! :) Integration is easy and it also has image zooming and flick dismiss. But I had to comment some code out to remove `AFNetworking` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have the wrong view content mode, add this line to where after the image is being set:

> bottleImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: Hi, This didn't work I'm afraid. The problem is not with changing size of the image, more so it's position in the view hierarchy. Thanks

Comment: this is not only for changing the size, it modifies how the imageview behaves when the shape changes. in this case it should be redraw. maybe try adding [imageview setNeedsDisplay]? im not sure i understand your problem anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bottleImageView]
```

immediately after you add

```
[self.view addSubview:bottleImageView]
```